# jasper report subreprot variable in main report as it change

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

i want subreport variable in main report as that variable increment type "group"  so i want this value on every change to main report (if subreport variable update three time so it update main report variable three time with this value). is it possible then how. if not kindly suggest me a by pass of this problem .

Thanks